# Не могу запустить второй цикл игры нормально

Tags: python, tkinter

Смысл игры решать примеры на время и при желании пробовать сколько хочешь, только при каждой новой игре таймер и примеры начинаются заново , У меня запускается игра через старт, включается таймер и идут примеры, когда время заканчивается, при проигрыше надпись вы проиграли но попробуйте снова. принажатии кнопки старт игра запускается но не сначала как первая игра ,а как продолжение и только таймер заново запускается , надпись о проигрыше не уходит, при повторном проигрыше еще одна появляется, при выигрыше тоже самое

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
number_rounds = 2
#sec = 30
operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']
cound=40

def countdown(count):
    label['text'] = count
    global cound
    global ytr
    #global knop
    cound=count
    if count > 0:
        if ytr is True:
            root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    if cound == 0:
        lose=Label(root, text=  "You lose!\n But You can try  again ", bg="blue", font="arial 25").pack()
        #knop=Button(root,text="Play again!",command=start_name(_)).pack()
        lose.grid_destroy()
        start_game
    return count




def get_name(_):
    print("HELLO", contents.get())
    text = contents.get()
    if not text: return
    lbl['text'] = "Hello, " + contents.get()

    entry.destroy()

    start_game()






def create_task():
    x = random.randint(1, 20)
    y = random.randint(1, 20)
    return x, y



def check_results(actual, expected, frame):
    global number_rounds
    global operations

    print(actual, expected)
    if actual == expected:

        frame.destroy()
        number_rounds -= 1
        if number_rounds > 0:
            display_task(operations[0])
        else:
            operation, *operations = operations
            if cound!=0:
                print(cound)
                if operation != 'end':
                    number_rounds = 2
                    display_task(operation)
                else:
                    Label(root,text="You win").pack()
                    Label(root,text="Remained"+str(cound-1)+"seconds!").pack()
                    #knop=Button(root,text="Play again!",command=play_again).pack()
                    global ytr
                    ytr=False
                    l.destroy()
                    #lbl.grid_remove()###
          #  elif cound==0:
           #     Label(root,text="You lose!").pack()
           #     Label.grid_remove()



root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x500")
root.configure(background='lightblue')
label = tk.Label(root,font=("Helvetica",25))
label.place(x=35, y=15)


root.title("MATH GAME")
lbl = Label(root, text="PLAYER NAME", bg="lightblue")
timeX = Label(root, fg="green")
entry = Entry(width=15)
contents = StringVar()
entry['textvariable'] = contents

lbl.place(x=247, y=40)
entry.place(x=242, y=60)
timeX.place(x=235, y=180)

btn = Button(root, width=20, height=6, text="START GAME", bg="yellow")
btn.place(x=220, y=150)
btn.bind("<Button-1>", get_name)
ytr=True
Exitbtn = Button(root, width=10, height=2, text="EXIT", bg="red")

Exitbtn.bind("<Button-1>", quit)
Exitbtn.place(x=250, y=450)

b=0
def cont():
    b = countdown(15)




def start_game():
    btn.grid_remove()
    display_task(operations[0])
    b=countdown(15)



def display_task(operation):
    x, y = create_task()
    frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
    frame.place(x=150, y=150)


    if operation == 'add':
        expected = x + y
        op = '+'
    elif operation == 'subtract':
        expected = x - y
        op = '-'
    elif operation == 'multiply':
        expected = x * y
        op = '*'
    else:
        expected = round(x/y,1)
        op = '/'



    label_task = Label(frame, text=f"{x} {op} {y} = ?")
    label_task.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

    results = [expected] + [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(3)]
    random.shuffle(results)


    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[0]}",width=20,height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[0], expected, frame))
    button.grid(column=1, row=2)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[1]}",width=20,height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[1], expected, frame))
    button.grid(column=2, row=2)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[2]}",width=20,height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[2], expected, frame))
    button.grid(column=1, row=3)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[3]}",width=20,height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[3], expected, frame))
    button.grid(column=2, row=3)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: уточните в вопросе какой из них первый какой из них второй, что вообще где? ясно опишите действия хотябы что вы делаете что у вас происходят какие то проблемы

Comment: Смысл игры решать примеры на время и при желании  пробовать сколько хочешь, только при каждой новой игре таймер и примеры начинаются заново   , У меня запускается игра через старт, включается  таймер и идут примеры, когда время заканчивается, при проигрыше надпись вы проиграли но попробуйте снова. принажатии кнопки старт  игра запускается но не сначала как первая игра ,а как продолжение  и  только таймер заново запускается  , надпись о проигрыше не уходит, при повторном проигрыше еще одна появляется, при выигрыше тоже самое ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас была проблема с вызовом функции `start` заного при поражении, а так же ва нужно было сделать виджеты победы и поражения глобальными чтобы их скрывать при нажатии на кнопку старт.

P.s. использования `global` не рекомендуется потому что очень путается в приложении поиск переменной в котором присутствует это значение я бы рекомендовал вариант с использованием ООП

Вариант с ООП

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    ytr = True
    operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']
    number_rounds = 2
    cound = 40
    b = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("600x500")
        self.configure(background='lightblue')
        self.label = tk.Label(self, font=("Helvetica", 25))
        self.label.place(x=35, y=15)

        self.title("MATH GAME")
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text="PLAYER NAME", bg="lightblue")
        timeX = tk.Label(self, fg="green")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(width=15)
        self.contents = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry['textvariable'] = self.contents

        self.lbl.place(x=247, y=40)
        self.entry.place(x=242, y=60)
        timeX.place(x=235, y=180)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, width=20, height=6, text="START GAME", bg="yellow")
        self.btn.place(x=220, y=150)
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_name)
        Exitbtn = tk.Button(self, width=10, height=2, text="EXIT", bg="red")

        Exitbtn.bind("<Button-1>", quit)
        Exitbtn.place(x=250, y=450)

        self.lose = tk.Label(self, text="You lose!\n But You can try  again ", bg="blue", font="arial 25")
        self.text_win = tk.Label(self, text="You win")
        self.text_win_info = tk.Label(self)

    def start_game(self):
        if not self.ytr:
            self.ytr = True
            self.text_win.pack_forget()
            self.lose.pack_forget()
            self.text_win_info.pack_forget()
        self.btn.grid_remove()
        self.display_task(self.operations[0])
        self.b = self.countdown(15)

    def get_name(self, event):
        text = self.contents.get()
        if not text:
            return
        self.lbl['text'] = "Hello, " + self.contents.get()

        self.entry.destroy()

        self.start_game()

    def display_task(self, operation):
        x, y = random.randint(1, 20), random.randint(1, 20)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=200)
        self.frame.place(x=150, y=150)

        if operation == 'add':
            expected = x + y
            op = '+'
        elif operation == 'subtract':
            expected = x - y
            op = '-'
        elif operation == 'multiply':
            expected = x * y
            op = '*'
        else:
            expected = round(x / y, 1)
            op = '/'

        label_task = tk.Label(self.frame, text=f"{x} {op} {y} = ?")
        label_task.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

        results = [expected] + [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(3)]
        random.shuffle(results)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text=f"{results[0]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: self.check_results(results[0], expected))
        button.grid(column=1, row=2)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text=f"{results[1]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: self.check_results(results[1], expected))
        button.grid(column=2, row=2)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text=f"{results[2]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: self.check_results(results[2], expected))
        button.grid(column=1, row=3)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text=f"{results[3]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: self.check_results(results[3], expected))
        button.grid(column=2, row=3)

    def check_results(self, actual, expected):

        if actual == expected:

            self.frame.destroy()
            self.number_rounds -= 1
            if self.number_rounds > 0:
                self.display_task(self.operations[0])
            else:
                operation, *self.operations = self.operations
                if self.cound:
                    if operation != 'end':
                        self.number_rounds = 2
                        self.display_task(operation)
                    else:
                        self.text_win.pack()
                        self.text_win_info.config(text="Remained" + str(self.cound - 1) + "seconds!")
                        self.text_win_info.pack()
                        self.ytr = False
                        self.operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']

    def countdown(self, count):
        self.label['text'] = count
        self.cound = count
        if count != 0:
            if self.ytr:
                self.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(count - 1))
        elif not self.ytr:
            self.after_cancel(1)
        else:
            self.after_cancel(1)
            self.lose.pack()
            self.frame.destroy()
            self.btn.place(x=220, y=150)
            self.ytr = False
            self.operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']
        return count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

---

Вариант вашего кода немного исправленного

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

number_rounds = 2
# sec = 30
operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']
cound = 40


def countdown(count):
    label['text'] = count
    global cound
    global ytr
    global operations
    global frame
    cound = count
    if count > 0:
        if ytr is True:
            root.after(1000, lambda: countdown(count - 1))

    if not ytr:
        root.after_cancel(1)
    if cound == 0:
        frame.destroy()
        root.after_cancel(1)
        btn.place(x=220, y=150)
        ytr = False
        lose.pack()
        operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']
    return count


def get_name(_):
    print("HELLO", contents.get())
    text = contents.get()
    if not text:
        return
    lbl['text'] = "Hello, " + contents.get()

    entry.destroy()

    start_game()


def check_results(actual, expected):
    global number_rounds
    global operations
    global frame
    global ytr
    if actual == expected:

        frame.destroy()
        number_rounds -= 1
        if number_rounds > 0:
            display_task(operations[0])
        else:
            print(operations)
            operation, *operations = operations
            if cound != 0:
                if operation != 'end':
                    number_rounds = 2
                    display_task(operation)
                else:
                    text_win.pack()
                    text_win_info.config(text="Remained" + str(cound - 1) + "seconds!")
                    text_win_info.pack()
                    ytr = False
                    operations = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'end']


def start_game():
    global ytr
    if not ytr:

        ytr = True
        text_win.pack_forget()
        lose.pack_forget()
        text_win_info.pack_forget()
    btn.grid_remove()
    display_task(operations[0])
    b = countdown(15)


def display_task(operation):
    global frame
    x, y = random.randint(1, 20), random.randint(1, 20)
    frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
    frame.place(x=150, y=150)

    if operation == 'add':
        expected = x + y
        op = '+'
    elif operation == 'subtract':
        expected = x - y
        op = '-'
    elif operation == 'multiply':
        expected = x * y
        op = '*'
    else:
        expected = round(x / y, 1)
        op = '/'

    label_task = Label(frame, text=f"{x} {op} {y} = ?")
    label_task.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

    results = [expected] + [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(3)]
    random.shuffle(results)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[0]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[0], expected))
    button.grid(column=1, row=2)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[1]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[1], expected))
    button.grid(column=2, row=2)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[2]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[2], expected))
    button.grid(column=1, row=3)

    button = Button(frame, text=f"{results[3]}", width=20, height=6, bg="pink")
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: check_results(results[3], expected))
    button.grid(column=2, row=3)


root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x500")
root.configure(background='lightblue')
label = tk.Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 25))
label.place(x=35, y=15)

root.title("MATH GAME")
lbl = Label(root, text="PLAYER NAME", bg="lightblue")
timeX = Label(root, fg="green")
entry = Entry(width=15)
contents = StringVar()
entry['textvariable'] = contents

lbl.place(x=247, y=40)
entry.place(x=242, y=60)
timeX.place(x=235, y=180)

btn = Button(root, width=20, height=6, text="START GAME", bg="yellow")
btn.place(x=220, y=150)
btn.bind("<Button-1>", get_name)
ytr = True
Exitbtn = Button(root, width=10, height=2, text="EXIT", bg="red")

Exitbtn.bind("<Button-1>", quit)
Exitbtn.place(x=250, y=450)
lose = Label(root, text="You lose!\n But You can try  again ", bg="blue", font="arial 25")
text_win = Label(root, text="You win")
text_win_info = Label(root)
b = 0
root.mainloop()
```